# How do I open a browserAction popup, from within a pageAction popup?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

## Background

I'm writing a web extension to tag bookmarks, and then navigate to those bookmarks by those tags. (A side-note: initially I wanted to read the native tags, but this isn't actually exposed to the web extensions API, so instead I'm going to use `storage.local` to hold that information). I'm new to web extensions development.

I'm using the excellent [adambullmer/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension](https://github.com/adambullmer/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension) to build the extension using Vue.

## Issue

I will be setting up a browser action popup to manage bookmarks and tags. I will also be setting up a page action popup to add tags (and/or bookmark) the current active page. From the page action popup, I'm trying to add a convenience button to open the browser action popup (to manage the tags and bookmarks).

When clicking the button however, I get the error "Error: Incorrect argument types for browserAction.openPopup."

[image: Error: Incorrect argument types for browserAction.openPopup.]

## Code snippets

`src/page-action-popup/App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 h-full w-full">
    <button
      class="m-2 py-1 px-3 bg-gray-500 rounded-full"
      @click.prevent="openBrowserActionPopup"
    >
      Open a browser action (Vue event handler)
    </button>
    <button
      ref="browserActionButtonEventListener"
      class="m-2 py-1 px-3 bg-gray-500 rounded-full"
    >
      Open a browser action (native DOM event listener on DOM element)
    </button>
    <button
      ref="browserActionButtonProperty"
      class="m-2 py-1 px-3 bg-gray-500 rounded-full"
    >
      Open a browser action (onclick property on DOM element)
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    openBrowserActionPopup() {
      console.log('trying to open browser action popup');
      browser.browserAction.openPopup();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.browserActionButtonEventListener.addEventListener('click', this.openBrowserActionPopup);
    this.$refs.browserActionButtonProperty.onclick = this.openBrowserActionPopup;
    console.log(this.$refs.browserActionButtonEventListener);
  },
}
</script>
```

`src/manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/tigregalis/nav-by-tag",
  "developer": {
    "name": "tigregalis",
    "url": "https://github.com/tigregalis"
  },
  "description": "An extension for tagging bookmarks and navigating by them",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "*://*/*",
    "bookmarks",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/logo.svg",
    "48": "icons/logo.svg",
    "128": "icons/logo.svg"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "browser-action-popup.html",
    "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/logo.svg",
      "38": "icons/logo.svg"
    },
    "theme_icons": [
      {
        "dark": "icons/logo-dark.svg",
        "light": "icons/logo-light.svg",
        "size": 19
      },
      {
        "dark": "icons/logo-dark.svg",
        "light": "icons/logo-light.svg",
        "size": 38
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "page-action-popup.html",
    "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/logo-light.svg",
      "38": "icons/logo-light.svg"
    },
    "show_matches": ["*://*/*"]
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "browser_style": true
  }
}
```

## Resources I've looked at

- MDN:

  - [browserAction.openPopup()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup) which states "You can only call this function from inside the handler for a user action."
  - [User actions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/User_actions) which states that "User actions include the following: [...] Clicking a button in a page bundled with the extension."
  - MDN doesn't appear to cover this scenario, either for or against.
- Plenty of Google, Mozilla and StackOverflow searches: surely someone else has tried to do what I'm trying?

## Things I've tried

1. Initially I used a standard Vue event to try to call `browserAction.openPopup()`, which gives me the error above.
2. I tried naively adding a callback function as an argument to `browserAction.openPopup()`, but instead I get a new error about argument count.

[image: Error: Expected at most 0 arguments for openPopup(), got 1]

3. Having read the User Actions page I tried numerous different ways to set an event handler on the raw DOM element, see the code snippet above for two of those, and I get the same error

Comment: 1) Extensions can't have both page action and browser action, and manifestV3 will combine them into one action API in the future 2) openPopup is still experimental in Chrome as it has "attribution issues" per crbug so it's not even present in stable versions.

Comment: @wOxxOm is that right? have you got a link for that? I've been testing it in Firefox and can definitely show a button and a popup for both page actions and browser actions (tested in Release and Developer).

Comment: Chrome should display [this error](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:extensions/common/manifest_constants.cc;l=746;drc=a8faae057698a771cc47079c80f8f25303a71496?sq=package:chromium) when both are specified.

Comment: And [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/extensions/extension_installed_bubble.cc;l=61;drc=ceabe6ee4dacd49ec5a2e8d08ada9e9ad26d461e?sq=package:chromium) we can see how only one type is always retrieved, the same can be seen in other functions as well. See also https://crbug.com/893373 for the unifying effort.

Comment: @wOxxOm when you say unification, is this unification of Firefox and Chrome, or unification of page action and browser action, or both? Do you know whether this will effectively be deprecated in the future for all platforms?

Comment: 1) I mean the same thing I said in my first comment. 2) Chrome extension API developers couldn't care less about Firefox implementation. It just doesn't exist for them. As the linked bug says Chrome will have one `action` API.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue because i had to check **async** if a specific url was already opened in any tab (`browser.tabs.query`) in order to naviagte to that tab or open the popup. The problem is after the async call the callback isnt an input handler anymore.

Solution:
set the popup to the browser action and make a script (has to be a separat file). Here you can make async calls and `window.close()` if something else should happen.